# Well pump reads 125v on each terminal but wont come on

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, well-pump, sprinkler-system, irrigation

When we bought the house the pump was wired directly to the breaker on a 240v circuit. I went to add an outlet and a sprinkler controller between the two. The picture shows the old vs new set up. The motor wont come on but I read 125v on each terminal with my volt meter. I replaced the capacitor and still no dice. The motor is only about a year old and was working fine when the conversion started. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: checkj the voltage between the two hots at the receptacle.  Then at the pump relay.

Comment: First mistake was adding stuff to that circuit.  Second probably miswired something.

Comment: Yea I read 125v on each hot going into the pump relay. Going out of the pump relay. And on each terminal on the motor

Comment: so your multimeter tells you you have 120V on each hot, and 240 V beteen them at the motor

Comment: Yes. 125v on each hot for 250 at the motor.

Comment: Where is the switch for the pump or is that what you mean by the pump motor?  Pump switches have a bad habit of stopping to work, so need to check if you get power after the switch.

Comment: To turn on the pump the relay is wired to the controller where you can say water now, When water is turned on or off via the controller the 120v on each hot goes 000 to 120v depending on if its on/off. The motor has the two prong electrical switch on it and that's certainly getting electrical current, still get 125v on the electrical switch. The motor i believe is a Century 1.5hp modUSQ1152

Comment: give up on multimeter, and use a simple light bulb in a socket with wires and check if there is real 120 V voltage (and current). be careful with electricity on during testing.

Comment: You might have created loose connection that is just enough to show 120 V, but breaks down when drawing current. The light bulb test

Comment: Do you actually measure 250V (or 240V, etc. anything close) anywhere? Check where you have 125V for each hot-to-neutral and see if you have 250V **between the two hots**. Because if someone messed up the panel (single breakers instead of double, moved around; regular double replaced with tandem; etc.) then you have have **0V** between the hots and no 250V motor will ever run until that is fixed. But you can't tell from the *separate* 125V readings.

Comment: Did you read 125V with one multimeter probe on one hot, and the other probe on the other hot? 125+125 = 250 but it also =0 if you wired the same 125V two times

Comment: Motor was working fine before you changed the wiring == you made an error in changing the wiring.

Comment: So I get 125 off the receptacle and it does power the controller. In the Relay if I unplug both outputs and test each differently I still get 125 on each. I just tried to touch both hot terminals on motor with multimeter however and I do get a 000 reading when individual gets 125 each. I did not mess with the breaker at all. Breaker is a 40amp double breaker with both hots in it and no neutral. I assumed as I wasnt touching the breaker connection and they both worked it would work again just splicing one hot for the receptacle. Could it be the relay thats configured wrong or what is the fix?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add some pics of your actual wiring around the relay.

Comment: will post some pics tomorrow morning

Answer (score 4):

You got twisted around and managed to put both pump "hot" wires on the same pole of the supply.

Or, one of them was abruptly disconnected.

Normally, this happens when someone rearranges the circuit breakers, doesn't understand what a tandem is, or installs a GE thin 2-pole breaker with a hammer. Thus they land both poles on the same AC power phase.  However in your case you did not disturb the panel since it last worked.

But since your power stops at a receptacle enroute, maybe there's a problem there. To start with, don't wire both poles to the receptacle.  Have one hot pole bypass the receptacle altogether - it will keep things simple and allow that receptacle to be upgraded to GFCI, which it probably should be, eh?

I could also see it happening if you tried splitting the receptacle to feed both poles to it, forgot to break the tab, and the resulting short circuit burned out a connection*. Because of the broken connection, the whole shebang would be fed off one pole and you'd never know it.

Or it could be someting completely out of left field, like a lost hot wire from the utility pole. Your water heater's resistance would connect the two poles/phases to each other, restoring weak power to the dead pole/phase, but would measure near 0V between them.

* you know, like from a backstab or improperly torqued screw terminal.  NEC 110.14 now requires torque screwdrivers for this reason.

Comment: Ok tomorrow I will open up the panel, receptacle and relay to be able to post some pictures. I did bypass the receptacle with one hot directly to the relay with only the other hot spliced to feed the outlet. I know it worked before the modifications but I am doubtful the breaker configuration is right even given how the previous owner has other electrical setups elsewhere in the house. Appreciate all the help and will post more details tomorrow when I can open it up. Thanks again!

Comment: I went to go take pictures and I figured out what was wrong. I did have two hots from the receptacle going the relay. Initially when I put it together I had a hot come loose and when I opened it back up I must have stuck that back into the pass through instead of the splice. Any ways all working now and have a nice working zoned solenoid system. Thanks for all the help everyone, it turned out pretty helpful!